# Add Country of manufacture from front-end for a product in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a form that enables users to add products from front-end. I was able to get all the details uploaded except for the country of Manufacture.

**Part of Code that I am using to add product from front-end**

$product->setName($data['pro_name']);

$product->setDescription($data['pro_des']);

// Country of Manufacture (What is the correct way to add country of manufacture)

$product->setCountryOfManufacture($data['country']);

Comment: can u please paste your code. So that we will try to debug it. Without code its hard to say where the bug is........

Comment: I have updated my query please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the data of country of manufacture as `$product->setCountryOrigin($data['country']);`

Make sure you are calling the data with 'country' then you have to set it as shown above.

Comment: I am getting the correct country code in $data['country'] as i am using the default listing available in magento and I have also used setcountryofmanufacture also but that also didn't work out.

Comment: Did u try with the suggested one?

Comment: Yes i did but no success.

Comment: can you check is your product type(the produc type that you are going to add) is selected in the attribute of country_of_manufacture in Admin

Comment: Yes I was getting all other details correct  for the product except for country.I was searching member functions for this in core files but got no success whereas member functions for other attributes were there!!

Comment: so if the other details are saving to db, make an 'echo' for those product details after execution of the save function. Then check does it displays the country or not

Comment: Dude it does echo the data that I am getting in country but i believe its not the correct function to save country of manufacture and the data being saved is already being displayed in admin so whats the point when in echoing the data when I already knwow which data is being pushed in db and which is not

Comment: check the country_origin column in db for the newly added product.

Answer (score 0):

$product->setCountryOfManufacture('DE');

2-letter country ISO code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 ,
 DE for Germany